# fbconnect with java play framework

Tags: java, playframework, fbconnect

I am using the fbconnect module in my play application but I get the following error.

**The file {module:fbconnect}/app/controllers/FBConnect.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : play.modules.fbconnect.FBConnectPlugin cannot be resolved**

I downloaded the fbconnect from [Here](https://github.com/murz/play-fbconnect).
Renamed the folder to fbconnect and put it in

```
C:/play/myproject/modules
```

In the dependencies.yml I put

```
require:
- play -> fbconnect 0.6
```

In C:/play/myproject/conf/application.config

```
# Facebook Connect
# ~~~~~
fbconnect.id=APP_ID
fbconnect.apiKey=API_KEY
fbconnect.secret=APP_SECRET
fbconnect.model=models.User
fbconnect.landUrl=/
```

What I am doing wrong. after downloading the fbconnect and making the required changes in dependencies.yml and application.conf. I run play dependencies as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just wondering - which version of play is this?  If 1.+, any reason why you would prefer this over social secure?

Comment: @ali haider what is social secure?

Comment: if you're using play 1.+ and not 2.+, you could look into socialsecure (http://www.playframework.org/modules).  I am not sure if socialsecure is available for play 2.0+.

Comment: @ali haider I am using 1.something

Comment: Is there any tutorial which explains how to use this module for implementing login with facebook for my site ?

Answer (score 0):

The following URL provided more details on secure social (with play framework 1.0+):

http://www.playframework.org/modules/securesocial-0.2.4/home

If you are looking to work with the social graph and not just auth, I would recommend either restFB or batchFB.

Steps:
For Setup:
Either use:

```
play install socialsecure-0.2.4
```

or add to dependencies.yml file

```
require:
  -play -> securesocial 0.2.4
```

& then run

```
play deps
```

Add the route to the routes file:

```
*       /auth       module:securesocial
```

Add the following to whichever controller class that needs authentication:

```
@With( SecureSocial.class )
public class Application extends Controller {
```

Ensure that your provider e.g. twitter or facebook are in the provider list in the application.conf file.  Also  ensure that you have the correct key/ID & secret for your app (specified in the application.conf file).  Once done, ensure that your references to securesocial are in place (if not, run play eclipsify or the appropriate command for whichever IDE you are using).  Once done, launch the app and test facebook (or other provider link) - ensure that the facebook return URL is correctly specified in the facebook app (on facebook).

One can modify the main.html page etc as needed to ensure that you use the CSS/content/login display as needed.

If using groovy templates, you can add the following to your html view to display some user information:

```
 <h2><img src="${user.avatarUrl}" width="40px" height="40px"/> Welcome    ${user.displayName}</h2>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I just need auth . I am very new to java and play framework can you please guide me ?

Comment: go to the github page for securesocial (java demo): https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/java/demo - go over the config file (securesocial and application.conf) as well as the controller/service/views for reference.  It should not take too long to go over the demo.

Comment: i downloaded it actually i have play in C directory and then my project inside play. should I keep this module in the my project modules folder or play modules ?

Comment: if you use the 'play install securesocial-0.2.4' command from your command prompt, that should add securesocial in your modules directory (inside the play directory).  Then you can add the securesocial reference in your application.conf file (inside the conf directory of your project)

Comment: in your application.conf file: require:
        - play -> securesocial 0.2.4

Comment: Do i need to add some controller or not ? I want the facbook oprion to appear on my login page which is http://localhost:9000/login and when I click on it it should authenticate me using facebook and then redirect me to http://localhost:9000/ with user logged in

Comment: If you simply copy the controller (as a test) from the demo URL above (along with the service), use the securesocial.conf file (with your application's facebook ID/secret), you should be able to hit FB.  Sometimes, there may be issues with testing via localhost (behavior may be different at times between chrome and FF) - if that causes any issues, change the host file on your computer (or use a free test VM on any cloud service) to get around that issue

Comment: play -> securesocial 0.2.4 should be added in application.conf or dependencies.yml

Comment: Your last comment just floated above my head :)

Comment: in the depencencies.yml file (or include "securesocial.conf" in the application.conf file as per the demo).  When testing against FB, you must have registered your application with FB (and in return received a FB ID/KEY, that goes in the securesocial.conf file).  While testing with FB, you may have issues if you're running your app as localhost and not an IP address (for which I suggestd a few options as workarounds).

Comment: is it not right if I put play -> securesocial 0.2.4 in dependencies.yml and put the FB key and secret in application.conf file

Comment: add the FB ID/key in the securesocial.conf file (as opposed to the application.conf file)

Comment: but there is no file securesocial.conf in play/modules/socialsecure/conf

Comment: go to the demo URL: github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/java/demo & copy their securesocial.conf file (from the conf directory of the application) - change/add the FB id/key in there.  if it does not work, I can update the post with another sample in a few hours

Comment: Can you please post a detail answer according to my situation as I described it to you ? I will be highly thankful to you.

Comment: I can now hit facebook once I give my login details of fb I redirects me to localhost:9000/*-_- I want to be redirected to apllication controller/userindex method how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing Facebook sign-in as well as other networks sign-in (like twitter or google), I suggest you pick an up-to-date library in Java, the problem with 1.x modules is that the method the networks used to communicate with their APIs are generaly outdated.

I wanted to do a Facebook and Google sign-in, and tried to use secure social for 1.2.4, the problem is Google now uses OAuth2 instead of first OAuth. I even tried to change the module using the source code from the play 2.0 scala securesocial, and "translate" it to java.

So I just picked a java library (wich are generaly uptodate), scribe ( https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java ), and it worked perfectly fine.

What I exactly did :

- Check scribe-java github page
- Download the fork I wanted from the fork list
- Build from Maven
- Coded what I needed

Good luck with your app.